# I don't know add picture to my company to the navbar - angular12

Tags: html, css, angular, image, navbar

I can't add logo to the navbar on my angular website.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink=""><img src="/src/assets/images/Nikiikejks.png" alt=""></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" routerLink=""  routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Domov</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="menu" routerLinkActive="active-link">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active-link">O nás</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contact" routerLinkActive="active-link">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link
{
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active-link
{
  color: #64cff7;
}
.navbar
{
  background-color: #f7dfde;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #777 ;
}
.navbar-brand {
  width:150px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  height: 30px;
  /* put value of image height as your need */
  float: left;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

I tried add path image and in css add some parameters, but it doesn't works.
I don't know, if I have bad size of picture or what?

Thank you.

Comment: `<img src="assets/images/Nikiikejks.png"` see that is a path relative and starts in assets folder. The reason is that Angular copy all your folder "assets" to "dist" folder. Using relative allow you "play" with base href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to leave the folder `app` first, and after that, go to the assets.

I don't know your folder structure, but if you currently are on `app.component` or in the folder `app`, your path should be: `../assets/images/Nikiikejks.png`.

Comment: It works, lot of thanks,  you are God now for me :). Have a good day.

Comment: @manjiro, has no relation with where you has the app.component. Angular create an unique index.html, a bundes files (.js) and copy the "assets" folder where you indicate in angular.json. You need use a relative path start where the index.html is. If you build in production generally you has your app in a "dist" folder. Check this folder where is assets and where is the .html

Comment: I don't think so. At least, when I want to put a `src` for an image, I usually have to use the path from my current file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the image quality. It has nothing to do with making it functional or not. When `img` is not shown you either have a wrong `path` (instead of `/src/assets` you need `assets/etc`) or wrong `extension` (your image is `.png` and not `.jpg` or the other way around)

Comment: extension is correct (image is .png in path and folder is also .png. But src = "/ src / assets / images / Nikiikejks.png" only offers me this path, no other.

Comment: check the first probability then. Your path is wrong.